# Redirect URL (on authentication phase using API)

Tags: docusignapi

I am new into this DocuSign universe so, I have a simple question: why do I need a Redirect URL (on authentication phase through API) when I don't have a website or something similar. How can I use all the facilities offered by DocuSign API without having this redirect URL ?

I need to make an automation that will be able to "connect" to DocuSign and do all the stuff available through the API.

Thank you

Comment: if you dont have any website where you will integrate it?

Comment: Into a robot. I need to build a custom activity that will have all the functionalities needed to use DocuSign features. But, I figured out the solution: just add http://localhost:5000 and you will have the response from DocuSign displayed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add localhost:5000 and you will have the response from DocuSign displayed :)